# Possible to upgrade cartridges on OpenShift online?

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I have a WildFly 8.1.0CR1 instance on my free OpenShift Online account. Now I see that a new version of WildFly is available (WildFly 8.1.0Final).

Is it possible to upgrade it without removing the cartridge and adding it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to remove the cartridge and re-install it, however, since you can not remove a web_framework cartridge (because it is the main cartridge on the gear) then you would need to create a new gear and migrate your application to it.